# How to get mongodb to start at boot time in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I have a stock install of Ubuntu 14, installed a few weeks ago. I installed mongodb with apt-get. When I run

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

then the service runs correctly and I can access all the mongodb goodness. However, whenever I reboot it will not start automatically. I have tried running update.rc or whatever it is called, and it claims to run successfully however still no luck.

Is this a known issue? How can I diagnose it? And I guess, most importantly, how can I make it start at reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding any service to startup try:

```
sudo update-rc.d <service_name> defaults
```

If that doesn't work you can add your start command in `/etc/rc.local` before the line `exit 0`

Comment: @user3690202, can you check if mongodb is recognized by running `service --status-all` ?

Comment: It returns: [ - ]  mongodb  for mongodb. As I mentioned, i can start it with service manually, it just doesnt auto-start. This is a stock standard install from the newly released ubuntu 14 with mongodb installed by apt-et. Nothing special anywhere - surely others must have this problem too?

Comment: @user3690202, You can also add `sudo service mondodb start` in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Looks like its the only way to work around a bug in Ubuntu 14/mongodb